# ConstraintLayout & FrameLayout wrap_content then FrameLayout show half content

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I don't known why FrameLayout inside ConstraintLayout, and both use wrap_content, then the last item in the RecycleView just show half content.
If I remove FrameLayout, direct use recycleview, it can work!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/finance_bg_book_list_dialog">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/finance_bg_book_list_toolbar"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="@string/finance_book"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="?fontSizeLarge"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/finance_ic_toolbar_shelf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vulturLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/vulturLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvToolbarTitle">
        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_contentCode="successful"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some horizontal constraints on your textview.
ex : app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf=

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you set a dimension for the `RecyclerView` height. if you use the `FrameLayout` with a `wrap_content` height, your `RecyclerView` will not be scrollable and it will own show half the item at the last based on the screen size

Comment: but use LinearLayout to replace ConstraintLayout, it can work.